# Do not open any interlinked projects while opening the master project

Tags: project2007

I have a master project with tasks that are linked to around 15 different projects. When I try to open my master project, all interlinked child projects are also opening which causes me issues when I try to open my master project from a slow internet connection. Is there are way I can disallow opening any child projects when opening my master project?

Comment: are you talking about Visual studio projects?

Comment: I mean MS Project Professional 2007 as I mentioned in my tag.